# How to Reduce the Maximum Upload File Size?

Tags: uploads

In my website there are many authors who can publish posts but some of them are uploading images bigger than 1M , and I want to reduce the max upload size to 500 kb.

Comment: try this plugin http://wpgogo.com/development/max-image-size-control-plugin.html#english

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can forbid uploads of a specific size (or for other reasons) in the `wp_handle_upload_prefilter` hook that is used in the [`wp_handle_upload()` function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_handle_upload).

It get's the file array passed, it's a single item in [the PHP standard superglobal `$_FILES`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) one that is documented in the [PHP Manual: POST method uploads](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Just create a function and add it to the filter. Inside your hook, check for the filesize and set `$file['error']` to your error message like "Files larger than X bytes are prevented from uploads".

```
add_filter('wp_handle_upload_prefilter', function($file) {
    $size = $file['size'];
    if ($size > 500 * 1024) {
       $file['error'] = '"Files larger than X bytes are prevented from uploads.';
    }
    return $file;
});
```

This method does not technically permit the upload which means, your server is still receiving the upload data of the file from the users browser. It's just thrown away afterwards.

To prevent uploads of certain size at the server level, you need to configure your server accordingly for that which depends on what you use.

Comment: wow thank you very much. It is right. it is work in local server but in my website hostgator there is error 'Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /home/***/public_html/wp-content/themes/***/functions.php on line 17"

Comment: @AboSami - That's because on hostgator you're using PHP 5.2 or so but the syntax I use is making use of [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as featured in PHP 5.3. Replace it with some [PHP 5.2 compatible callback](http://php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php) instead. The rest of the code should just work the same, it's more or less a way of writing.

Comment: I don't know about using php5.3 if you know please , any way thank you very much MR hakre. ^_^

Comment: @AboSami - [Changes between PHP 5.2 and PHP 5.3 are outlined already](http://www.php.net/manual/en/migration53.changes.php).

Comment: hakre's code above worked fine for me.
Only error in code is extra " mark at begining of the line - Files larger than X bytes are prevented from uploads.